# How to pass all requests to handler using Visual Studio Development server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an empty ASP.NET project with  single HttpHandler, saved in Index.ashx. I want all requests to go through this,

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

I've modified my project project properties so that it loads that handler by default. However, if I type a different Url in the browser it won't be passed through that handler. How do I get it to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...and to explicitly answer my question, you can add something like this to your `web.config` file (which can also be done through the IIS Manager GUI):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="RequestHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="WebApplication6.RequestHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

where "name" is an arbitrary name and "type" is the fully-qualified class name (with namespace).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is generally achieved via HttpModule and not via HttpHandler. The module can intercept all requests and modify request/responses as per need.

Comment: http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/08/15/Developing-IIS7-web-server-features-with-the-.NET-framework.aspx yeah....a module does sound like a better fit. thanks. now i have to learn how to write one of these instead !! handlers were simple :(

Comment: i'm still a little confused as to which i should be using though. a module sounds appropriate because it acts on *all* requests, but really, i just want it to *handle* the response. i'm building a url router. the app should take the request url, search through a list of routes, and then call the appropriate methods and return a response. modules aren't response for returning responses like that, are they?

Comment: @Ralph, in your case, module will not be generating response - it will simply sends the request to correct handler (url routing). Your module don't have to deal with response per say. BTW, routing is already available in .NET 4.

Comment: @VinayC: You mean via the MVC framework? I want to build my own :) With full regex support like Django. So the module can directly call the handler? In IIS it looks like you can set up handlers to handle certain file types based on the file extension. Would I *not* set any handlers in IIS (only the module) and call the handler directly then? Is there a code example for this?

Comment: @Ralph, routing can be used for ASP.NET web forms - it is not meant to be only for MVC framework. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx. As such, routing can become complicated because for correct implementation, you must edit the response and restore original urls (i.e. URLs as appeared in requests) - so my suggestion would be to use the one provided by ASP.NET. Regardless, here's old code sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx. Yet another way would be to use reflector to see ASP.NET routing implementation and learn from it.

Comment: @VinacyC: Still not sure what you mean by "restore the original urls"... why would I be modifying them at all? I meant a code example of explicitly calling the handler... is that how you're supposed to do it?

Comment: @Ralph, let's say request was made at url "\xyz\a.aspx" and you route it to "\abc\x.aspx". Now x.aspx page would, by default, generate html that will have form's action url as "\abc\x.aspx". But it should have been "\xyz\a.aspx" (as original url). So restoring urls is strictly not necessary but essential for transparent (from user's perspective) routing.

Comment: @VinayC: Well, I'm not going to be redirecting the URL to any aspx page. It's all going to be handled by controllers and template files. Also, I don't know why the form's action URL would be that... if you leave the action blank, it should post to the same URL, not its physical location. Lastly, the beauty of my routes is that they can be converted back to links, which could easily be placed as the action parameter. I don't think it should be a problem at all.